# 14.04 - Network Manager takes too much time reconnecting after resume/wake

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, suspend, iwlwifi

I have an Intel wireless network card in my notebook. Whenever I resume/wake/unhibernate my computer it takes about a minute or so in order to be able to connect to the Internet again. It's just too much! I know it isn't hardware issue, as I have windows 8 on the very same machine and it reconnects seamlessly, so the software running has no idea that internet connectivity has been suspended. Is it something wrong with how Ubuntu handles networking, or is it a problem with my configuration?

Comment: You mean when you shut the lid? Suspend and hibernate are not the same, so you have to be explicit here. Can you `ping` your Windows 8 install when the machine is in a similar state?

Comment: I meant both after suspend and hibernate. Windows 8 works flawlessly in all cases.

Comment: Can you ping the Windows 8 machine in either state?

Comment: Could you specify what do you mean by that? I don't have any kind of OS virtualization on my laptop, it can boot either to Windows or Ubuntu

Comment: Boot Windows 8. Find the local IP address with `ipconfig`. With another device on the network, use the `ping` command with the IP address and see if it responds.

Comment: To troubleshoot the problem, can you login to your router with another PC and check how soon the Ubuntu send DHCP request to your router upon boot up and how soon the router response. Then check again the same thing by login to your Windows on the same notebook. If the DHCP response to the router is delay, then we can at least know Ubuntu is not doing the right thing. Also, have you ever tried set a static IP address in Ubuntu? How soon it can connect to the internet under static IP?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to force a network restart and a wifi scan after resume. I will adapt the instructions I gave [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/521429/271) for another problem.

First, you need to create a small service script which will be triggered automatically by the system every time you resume. Run this command:

```
gksu gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_restart_net
```

Add the following content:

```
case "${1}" in
    resume|thaw)
        service networking restart
        iwlist scan
;;
esac
```

Save and reboot. Now try to suspend and resume to see if it's working.

Comment: this will make the re-connection faster?

Comment: I've added the lines to the file you pointed to. It didn't work.

Comment: @wxl forcing a scan should make the detection of a wireless network faster.

Comment: My theory is the scan already occurs, but Windows doesn't kill the connection on sleep.

Comment: It could be, but I doubt it. If Windows weren't killing the connection, the sleep status would consume a lot of energy. Anyway, it should be possible to tweak settings to keep the wifi always on, but there is little reason for using the sleep mode then.