# Wifi not working after suspend

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, suspend, lenovo

I have notebook Lenovo Z500, his wireless hw: Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (vendor - Intel). When I close the lid notebook suspends and when it is woken up wifi is disabled and there is no way to enable it. `rfkill` says that it is hardware blocked. I've tried to restart network manager, added `iwlwifi` module to SUSPEND_MODULES in `/etc/pm/config.d/config`, but only rebooting helps. On Win 7 everything is fine. Are there any ways to solve this problem? It's very annoying. My Ubuntu version is 14.04 LTS

`lsmod | grep wmi` output:

```
snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi

snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi

snd                    69238  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the output of `lsmod | grep wmi`?

Comment: attached to the post

Comment: My bad, after reading your question again, I realized my request was not really necessary. Does it work if you issue `sudo rmmod iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi` after suspend?

Comment: it tries to connect to network but it fails (disconnects and tries again and again). I had to rmmod and modprobe iwldvm module

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, you solve the problem by manually issuing `rmmod iwldvm && modprobe iwldvm`. In order to get it to work automatically after a resume, you need to create a script.

I will adapt the instructions posted in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/92235/271) to suit your needs. Run:

```
gksu gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_fix_wifi
```

Add the following content:

```
case "${1}" in
    resume|thaw)
        rmmod iwldvm && modprobe iwldvm
;;
esac
```

Save the file and reboot. Try to suspend and resume to see if it works.

Comment: this did not help :(

Comment: It works if you do it in the terminal but not with the script?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. You a little bit misunderstood me. Module reloads and notebook tries to connect but unsuccessful. I can see connecting icon but finally it says: "network disconnected" and tries again and again

Comment: ...and `rfkill` says it's not hardware blocked, right?

Comment: right. not blocked but can't connect

Comment: Ok. Does it work if you switch it off and back on? Like `rfkill block wifi && rfkill unblock wifi`?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I've also tried ip link set wlan0 up and restart network manager service, but no

Comment: The last thing I can think of is trying to blacklist the `iwldvm` module all together. After this, I have no more ideas... :(